# ["str",[Tilt::StringTemplate]][ "erb" text appears over the dashing widget

Tags: ruby, dashing

while testing the ProgressBars widget, i get this text over the top of the widget
"
["str", [Tilt::StringTemplate]]["erb", [Tilt::ErubisTemplate, Tilt::ERBTemplate]]["rhtml", 
[Tilt::ErubisTemplate, Tilt::ERBTemplate]]["erubis", [Tilt::ErubisTemplate]]["etn", 
[Tilt::EtanniTemplate]]["etanni", [Tilt::EtanniTemplate]]["haml", [Tilt::HamlTemplate]]["mab", [Tilt::MarkabyTemplate]]["liquid", [Tilt::LiquidTemplate]]["radius", [Tilt::RadiusTemplate]]["markdown", [Tilt::RedcarpetTemplate, Tilt::RedcarpetTemplate::Redcarpet2, Tilt::RedcarpetTemplate::Redcarpet1, Tilt::RDiscountTemplate, Tilt::BlueClothTemplate, Tilt::KramdownTemplate, Tilt::MarukuTemplate]]["mkd", [Tilt::RedcarpetTemplate, Tilt::RedcarpetTemplate::Redcarpet2, Tilt::RedcarpetTemplate::Redcarpet1, Tilt::RDiscountTemplate, Tilt::BlueClothTemplate, Tilt::KramdownTemplate, Tilt::MarukuTemplate]]["md", [Tilt::RedcarpetTemplate,t::RedcarpetTemplate::Redcarpet2, Tilt::RedcarpetTemplate::Redcarpet1, 
Tilt::RDiscountTemplate, Tilt::BlueClothTemplate, Tilt::KramdownTemplate, Tilt::MarukuTemplate]]["textile", [Tilt::RedClothTemplate]]["rdoc", [Tilt::RDocTemplate]]["wiki", [Tilt::WikiClothTemplate, Tilt::CreoleTemplate]]["creole", [Tilt::CreoleTemplate]]["mediawiki", [Tilt::WikiClothTemplate]]["mw", [Tilt::WikiClothTemplate]]["ad", [Tilt::AsciidoctorTemplate]]["adoc", [Tilt::AsciidoctorTemplate]]["asciidoc", [Tilt::AsciidoctorTemplate]]["html", [Tilt::PlainTemplate]]
"

using this job:

```
SCHEDULER.every '60s', :first_in => 0 do |job|
progress_items = [{ name: "used", value: 10 }, { name: "free", value: 90 }]
send_event( 'progressbars', {title: "SPDB01", progress_items: []} )
end
```

and this dashboard: 
 
      $(function() {

```
  Dashing.widget_base_dimensions = [400, 400]
  Dashing.numColumns = 5
      });
      </script>    
<div class="gridster">
 <ul>
   <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
       <div data-id="CLUSTER1" data-view="Fullpie" data-title="CLUSTER1"></div>
 </li>
 <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">
   <div data-id="progressbars" data-view="ProgressBars" data-title="SPDBD01"></div>
 </li>
    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
       <div data-id="SPAPP01" data-view="Fullpie" data-title="SPAPP01"></div>
 </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

i am using debian 7.3 on vmplayer

Comment: solved at https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/324

Comment: Better put the solution in answer as well